# Changing agda version recognized by agda command

Tags: agda, agda-mode

Now that `agda-2.6.3` is released, I have download this new version. The problem I am running into is that my system still recognizes `agda-2.6.2.2` as the default version: when I run `agda --version` in the command line, it returns `Agda version 2.6.2.2`. I know that I can change which agda version emacs is using by using `C-c + C-x + C-s` while in an agda file. But, and the main problem I need to solve, is that when I run `make check` from the terminal command line in a certain directory with agda files, it seems to load and try to check the agda files with `2.6.2.2` which causes certain errors.

I have changed the symlinks `.cabal/bin/agda` and `.cabal/bin/agda-mode` to point to the new version of agda, but this has not fixed the issue: I still get `Agda version 2.6.2.2` when I run `agda --version` (and get an error when I run make check in the directory mentioned earlier). This has changed something though. When I type `C-c + C-x + C-s` in emacs and press return on an empty mini-buffer, it tells me `The Agda mode's version (2.6.3) does not match that of agda (2.6.2.2)`. So somehow this was able to change the version of `agda-mode`, but not of `agda`.

Does anyone know why this might be the case? Additionally, does anyone know how to change the agda version recognized by `agda` command? For reference, I am using Fedora linux.

EDIT :

Here is the output of `ls -l ~/.cabal/bin/agda*`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 rymndbkr rymndbkr 104 Feb 10 16:11 agda -> ../store/ghc-8.10.7/Agda-2.6.3-6fc120f20f643b232442c35c8a992031336f40cabc1db375133c993b327332d8/bin/agda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 rymndbkr rymndbkr 125 Feb 11 17:09 agda-2.6.2.2 -> /home/rymndbkr/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.7/Agda-2.6.2.2-759e1b1bce7dc909fddfed32b6b0bb75821632ef6ac10590d66d5b7aaef1066d/bin/agda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 rymndbkr rymndbkr 104 Feb  7 21:35 agda-2.6.3 -> ../store/ghc-8.10.7/Agda-2.6.3-6fc120f20f643b232442c35c8a992031336f40cabc1db375133c993b327332d8/bin/agda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 rymndbkr rymndbkr 109 Feb 10 16:11 agda-mode -> ../store/ghc-8.10.7/Agda-2.6.3-6fc120f20f643b232442c35c8a992031336f40cabc1db375133c993b327332d8/bin/agda-mode
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 rymndbkr rymndbkr 130 Feb 11 17:06 agda-mode-2.6.2.2 -> /home/rymndbkr/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.7/Agda-2.6.2.2-759e1b1bce7dc909fddfed32b6b0bb75821632ef6ac10590d66d5b7aaef1066d/bin/agda-mode
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 rymndbkr rymndbkr 109 Feb  7 21:35 agda-mode-2.6.3 -> ../store/ghc-8.10.7/Agda-2.6.3-6fc120f20f643b232442c35c8a992031336f40cabc1db375133c993b327332d8/bin/agda-mode
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 rymndbkr rymndbkr 127 Jun  2  2022 AllNonAsciiChars -> ../store/ghc-8.10.5/agda-stdlib-utils-1.7-ded3c0cc15b1bd55ef2f27702179b83d259612c9910ffc92fa1561024170cf5d/bin/AllNonAsciiChars
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 rymndbkr rymndbkr 129 Jun  2  2022 GenerateEverything -> ../store/ghc-8.10.5/agda-stdlib-utils-1.7-30b294f8e41a4fa403f9cc53aa1bdaad42507be6da4230825ad747024add7592/bin/GenerateEverything
```

Thanks to gallais in the comments, I ran `which agda`. Here is the result:

```
/usr/bin/agda
```

I think this means that the terminal command `agda` is looking for agda in the wrong place. But I don't know how to change this. So now my question is: how can I can I change the path of a shell command?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l ~/.cabal/bin/agda*`?

Comment: @gallais yup, sorry for the the late reply!

Comment: All seems OK. Could you possibly have an agda installed via your package manager too? What does `which agda` return?

Comment: @gallais . Ah, that might be it! I posted the result of `which agda`. Do you know how to change where the system looks for agda?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to uninstall the globally installed Agda using your package manager. Failing that, you should be able to put `~/.cabal/bin` before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` definition and that should hopefully mean that local installs would take precedence.